# Возникает ошибка в ветвлении. Постоянно выводится "данного треугольника не существует". Visual studio 2019

Tags: c++

```
#include iostream
#include cmath

void length(int x1, int x2, int x3, int y1, int y2, int y3)
{
    double AB, BC, AC;

    AB = sqrt(pow((x2 - x1), 2) - pow((y2 - y1), 2));
    BC = sqrt(pow((x3 - x2), 2) - pow((y3 - y2), 2));
    AC = sqrt(pow((x1 - x3), 2) - pow((y1 - y3), 2));

    if ((AB + BC > AC) && (BC + AC > AB) && (AC + AB > BC))
    {
        std::cout << "AB= " << AB << std::endl;
        std::cout << "BC= " << BC << std::endl;
        std::cout << "AC= " << AC << std::endl;
    }

    else
    {
     std::cout << "данного треугольника не существует" << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;

    std::cout << "Эта программа вычисляет параметры треугольника" <<
"(координаты точек - целые числа) " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Введите координату x1 точки A: ";
    std::cin >> x1;
    std::cout << "\nВведите координату y1 точки A: ";
    std::cin >> y1;
    std::cout << "\nВведите координату x2 точки B: ";
    std::cin >> x2;
    std::cout << "\nВведите координату y2 точки B: ";
    std::cin >> y2;
    std::cout << "\nВведите координату x3 точки C: ";
    std::cin >> x3;
    std::cout << "\nВведите координату y3 точки C: ";
    std::cin >> y3;
    length(x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

```
AB = sqrt(pow((x2 - x1), 2) + pow((y2 - y1), 2));
                            ^ - Теорема Пифагора
```

Comment: мда, вот и все мои знания в математике

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Какой еще более развернутый ответ нужен?!

Comment: @Harry, да, пожалуй, в данном случае более подходящим был бы совет изложить указание на ошибку в виде комментария, а не ответа.